# Axis 2 dependency and geronimo jars in war file after built with maven

Tags: maven, jboss, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm new to axis, please be patient.
I've generated java files from WSDL endpoint, and each java file has

`implements org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean{`

which means that I need to have dependency of axis2.jar in maven pom.xml in compile scope (please correct me if i'm wrong).

But that axis2.jar dependency also downloads a lot of geronimo files. But I'm using JBOSS. I don't actually want geronimo files in my war.

Is this really necessary to have these *geronimo* jars? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong when specify axis2.jar compile-time dependency in pom.xml?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
        <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer. I can use provided scope and move all these geronimo jars to the jboss lib folder, but would it be right to have in jboss another container runtimes? I thought actually that there should be an axis2 version for jboss with jboss runtime dependencies, but it seems it is not.

Comment: I have zero experience with JBoss, but googling "axis2 jboss" turned up this: http://wso2.com/library/3001 - good luck!

Comment: Thanks. (I now you think I ask questions before googling it, but actually I'm not). I do not need to deploy axis2 in jboss, I'm *embedding* it in my war. And it requires another server runtimes. That is suspicious enough to ask, as I was not able to find any information about that. Anyway you are trying to help and I appreciate that.

Comment: Ok, back on the case. Can you please update your question to include the `<dependency>` from your POM?

Comment: axis2 part of pom.xml added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the free online book "Maven: The Complete Reference" depicts your exact case in their section ["Conflict Resolution"](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-conflict)

The Apache Axis2 libraries you depend on implement part of the Java EE spec and thus have *compile* scope transitive dependencies on the Geronimo "Java EE Spec" libraries.  These spec libraries merely implement the Java EE standard. So if  you inspect the contents of (for example)

`jar -tf geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar`

You'll find (among other things).

```
javax/
javax/mail/
javax/mail/Address.class
javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException.class
javax/mail/Authenticator.class
(etc.)
```

So, there should be no harm in deploying these Geronimo jars with your application, but if it really bothers you (or if you do in fact encounter a problem), you can exclude the transitive dependencies with an `<exclusions>` block:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

JBoss ships its own spec jars, but you shouldn't bother going through the trouble of excluding the geronimo Jars unless you hit an actual issue.

Alternatively, you could consider just using the [JBoss Web Services](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws) if you know for sure that is your deployment container.